# Desafio de possibilidade em c,c++ ou matlab

Tags: c, c++, matemática, matlab, scilab

Estou precisando de um programa que me de as possibilidades da seguinte equação:

`x*y = 1700/57`

Sendo que `x` e `y` são reais positivos resultantes de dois números inteiros("a" e "b") diferentes de `1` a `300`.

Eu tentei mas acabou não dando certo e não sei aonde ta o erro.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x, i, a, b, res, xa=0, xb=0;
    int vetorA[300];
    int vetorB[300];

    for (a=0; a<=300; a++){

        for(b=0;b<=300; b++){

            if(a%b==0){// o resultado tem que ser um numero inteiro// nao sendo decimal

                xa++;
                xb++;
                a=vetorA[xa];   
                b=vetorA[xb];

            }// end if      

        }
    }


    for(i=0;i<=xa; i++){

        printf("valores de a === %d\n", vetorA[i]);

    }

    for(i=0;i<=xb; i++){

        printf("valores de b === %d\n", vetorB[i]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não acompanhado de texto, fica difícil de distinguir sua necessidade

Comment: estou precisando de um programa cujo o qual , me de as possibilidades da seguinte equação: x*y =1700/57. sendo que x e y são reais positivos resultantes de dois números inteiros diferentes de 0 a 300.

Comment: sou novo nesse site, nao sei como coloca direito

Comment: Edite sua pergunta, deixe claro para quem está chegando nela, lendo-a a primeira vez

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @PedroJoao, abaixo do corpo da pergunta, tem as tags [ `c`, `c++` ..] abaixo tem [ `compartilhar`, `editar`, ... ] ou [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/243061/edit)

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português, talvez queira fazer um **Tour**: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour ou dar uma olhada na **Central de Ajuda**: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour e verificar como efetuar perguntas de uma forma que sejam respondidas rapidamente, tente informar o que você já tentou e poste o seu código, dificilmente alguém fará o trabalho por você. Como você não tem uma ideia de como fazer o que está precisando, inicialmente é melhor fazer uma pesquisa e depois se tiver alguma dificuldade na programação pode voltar a perguntar aqui.

Comment: Qual o erro apresentado? O programa não imprime o resultado esperado?

Comment: já vi...obg. estou editando aqui

Comment: o programa nao imprimir os valores salvos

Comment: Os valores dos vetores não estão sendo alterados. Ele deve estar imprimindo ou zero ou lixo de memória aleatório

Comment: Note também que iterar sobre 300 elementos é no intervalo fechado em 0 e aberto em 300; ou então `i = 0; i < 300; i++`

Comment: Note também que `a%b == 0` é você verificar que `a` é múltiplo de `b`, essa operação por si só não retornará verdadeiro para todos os casos de `a` e `b` verdadeiros. Como `1700` não é múltiplo de `57`,  não existem dois inteiros tais que `a*b == 1700/57`. Tem algum engano no enunciado ou em assumir que existe espaço solução com dois inteiros

Comment: O que estou precisando é de um programa que me dê as possibilidades e seja filtrado pelas condições impostas pelo programa:
Por exemplo :
x*y=1700/57;
sendo que tanto x como y são números resultantes da divisão de dois números("a" e "b") ambos inteiros e não necessariamente múltiplos um do outro no intervalo de [1:300]

Comment: Você diz que `x` e `y` são reais positivos **resultantes** de `a` e `b`. Esse resultado é obtido por uma divisão? Subtração?

Comment: Ah, ótima edição. Agora eu entendi seu problema.

Comment: desisto dessa desafio. difícil demais...

Comment: A resposta atendeu às suas dúvidas? Então é o caso de [marcar a resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A equação à qual se deseja achar as raízes é:

```
x * y = 1700/57
```

Você precisa, para seu espaço solução, de dois números reais `x` e `y`. Mas `x` e `y` não são números reais quaisquer, eles são reais positivos, podendo ser representados pela fração de dois inteiros `a/b`, sendo que `1 <= a,b <= 300`. Note também que `x = a_x/b_x` e que `y = a_y/b_y`, não havendo nenhuma relação de igualdade ou diferença entre `a_x, b_x, a_y, b_y`, sendo as quatro variáveis inteiras independentes entre si.

Isso significa que:

[image: x * y = a_x/b_x * a_y/b_y = (a_x * a_y)/(b_x * b_y) = 1700/57]

Como nos é garantido que `a_x, b_x, a_y, b_y` são inteiros entre 1 e 300 (fechado), isso significa duas coisas:

1. a_x * a_y = 1700
2. b_x * b_y = 57

O que basicamente se restringe a achar dois divisores de 1700 ambos entre 1 e 300, e dois divisores de 57 entre 1 e 300.

## Divisores de 57

Para achar todos os pares de divisores de 57 entre 1 e 300, precisamos verificar quais são os números desse intervalo que dividem 57 e, então, verificar se o seu contra-ponto é menor que 300.

Não vou demonstrar, mas basta vasculhar pelos números inteiros no intervalo `[1, 57]` para a variável `b_x`, sendo então `b_y = 57/b_x`. Não há necessidade adicional de verificar `b_y`.

Código para achar todos os fatores `b_x`:

```
int bx_candidato;
for (bx_candidato = 1; bx_candidato <= 57; bx_candidato++) {
    if (57 % bx_candidato == 0) {
        printf("b_x %d, b_y %d\n", bx_candidato, 57/bx_candidato);
    }
}
```

> Armazenar os resultados num vetor fica para um momento posterior

## Divisores de 1700

A ideia é a mesma dos divisores de 57, porém aqui é necessário verificar se `a_y <= 300`. Também é necessário vasculhar apenas no intervalo `[1,300]`, pois não tem nenhum artifício matemático para reduzir o escopo de busca.

Portanto:

```
int ax_candidato;
for (ax_candidato = 1; ax_candidato <= 300; ax_candidato++) {
    if (1700 % ax_candidato == 0 && 1700/ax_candidato <= 300) {
        printf("a_x %d, a_y %d\n", ax_candidato, 1700/ax_candidato);
    }
}
```

> Armazenar os resultados num vetor fica para um momento posterior

## Resolvendo a questão

Note que achar `a_x` implica na existência de apenas um único `a_y`, assim como `b_x` e `b_y`.

O cerne do seu problema você pode encontrar aqui:

```
int divisores_1700[300];
int divisores_encontrados_1700 = 0;

int divisores_57[57];
int divisores_encontrados_57 = 0;
int ax_candidato;
int bx_candidato;

for (bx_candidato = 1; bx_candidato <= 57; bx_candidato++) {
    if (57 % bx_candidato == 0) {
        divisores_57[divisores_encontrados_57] = bx_candidato;
        divisores_encontrados_57++;
    }
}

for (ax_candidato = 1; ax_candidato <= 300; ax_candidato++) {
    if (1700 % ax_candidato == 0 && 1700/ax_candidato <= 300) {
        divisores_1700[divisores_encontrados_1700] = ax_candidato;
        divisores_encontrados_1700++;
    }
}
```

Em cima dos valores encontrados, qualquer combinação de `divisores_57` com `divisores_1700` atende ao problema. Para encontrar todas essas combinações:

```
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < divisores_encontrados_57; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < divisores_encontrados_1700; j++) {
        int a_x, a_y, b_x, b_y;

        a_x = divisores_1700[j];
        a_y = 1700/a_x;

        b_x = divisores_57[i];
        b_y = 57/b_x;

        printf("(%d/%d) * (%d/%d) == 1700/57\n", a_x, b_x, a_y, b_y);
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/XdWWTX).

Comment: Amigo Jefferson Quesado entendi a sua proposta e vou tratar de implementa-la aqui no meu PC e analisar os resultados. Muito obrigado pela ajuda e paciência!

Comment: @PedroJoao, se quiser, faz pouco mais de cinco minnutos que subi uma atualização da resposta com uma implementação no [ideone](https://ideone.com/XdWWTX), podendo validar mais rapidamente

Answer (score 2):

Apesar de ser uma técnica computacionalmente ineficiente, a igualdade `(xa * xb) / (ya * yb) = 1700 / 57` pode ser verificada por meio de `força bruta`.

São aproximadamente `8 Bilhões` de possibilidades que precisam ser testadas:

```
300 * 300 * 300 * 300 = 8.100.000.000
```

Nos meus testes em um `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz` fui capaz de testar todas as possibilidades em apenas `30ms`, utilizando o flag de otimização `-O3` do `GCC` e evitando operações de ponto flutuante (divisões) na comparação da igualdade:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int n = 0;
    int xa, xb, ya, yb;

    for( xa = 1; xa <= 300; xa++ )
        for( xb = 1; xb <= 300; xb++ )
            for( ya = 1; ya <= 300; ya++ )
                for( yb = 1; yb <= 300; yb++ )
                    if( (xa * xb == 1700) && (ya * yb == 57) )
                        printf( "[%d] ( %d * %d ) / ( %d * %d ) = 1700 / 57\n", ++n, xa, xb, ya, yb );

    return 0;
}
```

Compilando:

```
$ gcc -O3 teste.c -o teste
```

Testando:

```
$ time ./teste 
[1] ( 10 * 170 ) / ( 1 * 57 ) = 1700 / 57
[2] ( 10 * 170 ) / ( 3 * 19 ) = 1700 / 57
[3] ( 10 * 170 ) / ( 19 * 3 ) = 1700 / 57
[4] ( 10 * 170 ) / ( 57 * 1 ) = 1700 / 57
[5] ( 17 * 100 ) / ( 1 * 57 ) = 1700 / 57
[6] ( 17 * 100 ) / ( 3 * 19 ) = 1700 / 57
[7] ( 17 * 100 ) / ( 19 * 3 ) = 1700 / 57
[8] ( 17 * 100 ) / ( 57 * 1 ) = 1700 / 57
[9] ( 20 * 85 ) / ( 1 * 57 ) = 1700 / 57
[10] ( 20 * 85 ) / ( 3 * 19 ) = 1700 / 57
[11] ( 20 * 85 ) / ( 19 * 3 ) = 1700 / 57
[12] ( 20 * 85 ) / ( 57 * 1 ) = 1700 / 57
[13] ( 25 * 68 ) / ( 1 * 57 ) = 1700 / 57
[14] ( 25 * 68 ) / ( 3 * 19 ) = 1700 / 57
[15] ( 25 * 68 ) / ( 19 * 3 ) = 1700 / 57
[16] ( 25 * 68 ) / ( 57 * 1 ) = 1700 / 57
[17] ( 34 * 50 ) / ( 1 * 57 ) = 1700 / 57
[18] ( 34 * 50 ) / ( 3 * 19 ) = 1700 / 57
[19] ( 34 * 50 ) / ( 19 * 3 ) = 1700 / 57
[20] ( 34 * 50 ) / ( 57 * 1 ) = 1700 / 57
[21] ( 50 * 34 ) / ( 1 * 57 ) = 1700 / 57
[22] ( 50 * 34 ) / ( 3 * 19 ) = 1700 / 57
[23] ( 50 * 34 ) / ( 19 * 3 ) = 1700 / 57
[24] ( 50 * 34 ) / ( 57 * 1 ) = 1700 / 57
[25] ( 68 * 25 ) / ( 1 * 57 ) = 1700 / 57
[26] ( 68 * 25 ) / ( 3 * 19 ) = 1700 / 57
[27] ( 68 * 25 ) / ( 19 * 3 ) = 1700 / 57
[28] ( 68 * 25 ) / ( 57 * 1 ) = 1700 / 57
[29] ( 85 * 20 ) / ( 1 * 57 ) = 1700 / 57
[30] ( 85 * 20 ) / ( 3 * 19 ) = 1700 / 57
[31] ( 85 * 20 ) / ( 19 * 3 ) = 1700 / 57
[32] ( 85 * 20 ) / ( 57 * 1 ) = 1700 / 57
[33] ( 100 * 17 ) / ( 1 * 57 ) = 1700 / 57
[34] ( 100 * 17 ) / ( 3 * 19 ) = 1700 / 57
[35] ( 100 * 17 ) / ( 19 * 3 ) = 1700 / 57
[36] ( 100 * 17 ) / ( 57 * 1 ) = 1700 / 57
[37] ( 170 * 10 ) / ( 1 * 57 ) = 1700 / 57
[38] ( 170 * 10 ) / ( 3 * 19 ) = 1700 / 57
[39] ( 170 * 10 ) / ( 19 * 3 ) = 1700 / 57
[40] ( 170 * 10 ) / ( 57 * 1 ) = 1700 / 57

real    0m0.030s
user    0m0.030s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Comment: Força bruta nunca fica velha =]

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Porém, 30x mais lenta que a sua solução.